# Case sensitive like select SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, case-sensitive

So I have the following query:

```
select username from users where username like 'aDam%'
```

but the problem here is that its not case sensitive. this query will get also users named 'adam%', 'Adam%', etc..

**Question:** How do I get only 'aDam%' (make the query case sensitive)?

note: the % operator is important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Like is case insensitive it will not work on its own but one workaround is to use it together with the `SUBSTR` function

```
select username 
from users 
where username like 'aDam%' 
  and substr(username,1,4) = 'aDam'
```

Answer (score 5):

Before running the query you could set the [case_sensitive_like](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like) pragma to ON.

> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = boolean;
>
> The default behavior of the LIKE operator is to ignore case for ASCII
>   characters. Hence, by default 'a' LIKE 'A' is true. The
>   case_sensitive_like pragma installs a new application-defined LIKE
>   function that is either case sensitive or insensitive depending on the
>   value of the case_sensitive_like pragma. When case_sensitive_like is
>   disabled, the default LIKE behavior is expressed. When
>   case_sensitive_like is enabled, case becomes significant. So, for
>   example, 'a' LIKE 'A' is false but 'a' LIKE 'a' is still true.
>
> This pragma uses sqlite3_create_function() to overload the LIKE and
>   GLOB functions, which may override previous implementations of LIKE
>   and GLOB registered by the application. This pragma only changes the
>   behavior of the SQL LIKE operator. It does not change the behavior of
>   the sqlite3_strlike() C-language interface, which is always case
>   insensitive.

Then just run the query as it is.

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;
select username from users where username like 'aDam%';
```

Test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/23e18/1/0) on Sql Fiddle.

Comment: I like this as it's very explicit that you want the query to be case sensitive on this particular element and it doesn't have the overhead of complicating the SQL.

Comment: @xQbert The interesting thing is that this also works for a LIKE when the source varchar has a case-insensitive collation.  But if you use `=` you then you might have to add `COLLATE BINARY` to the search string.